# word boundaries of UTF-8 text in perl

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8

My perl script is provided with a string of characters in UTF-8 which could be in any language. I need to capitalize the first character of each word, and the remaining characters of the word converted to lower case. This must be done while leaving the text in UTF-8 format.

The following seems to work well enough when the text only contains latin characters

```
$my_string =~ s/([\w']+)/\u\L$1/g;
```

How can I get this to work in a UTF-8 string?

Comment: Perl doesn’t have UTF-8 strings.  It has character strings, which are in Unicode, and it has byte strings, which are in bytes.  What you have written there already works fine in current versions of Perl.  You may need something like like `use v5.12`, `use v5.14`, or `use feature "unicode_strings"` at the top of your compilation unit to make it work, but you should not need anything else.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that the web server I'm using still has 5.8 perl so unfortunately none of these suggestions are available to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [perlunicode](http://p3rl.org/unicode) for an overview of the facilities you need to be familiar with.  Basically, you are looking for something like `\p{LC}`.

Your problem space is not well-defined, though; not all scripts have a concept of character case.  The LC property will only match on scripts which do, so it should get you there.

Comment: ... although a closer replacement for \w is probably \p{Word}

Comment: Incidentally, does the \u and \L in "\u\L$1" always do the correct conversion to upper and lower case, or are there unicode replacements for these?

Comment: I believe they should DTRT if your Perl is recent enough.

Comment: Actually, stuff like `\p{LC}` still won’t work if you have a byte string not a character string. Plus the provided solution in the OP already works perfectly well in 5.14; write `use v5.14` at the top of your compilation unit and all will be well.  I never bother with `[\p{CWL}\p{CWT}\p{CWU}]` myself.

Comment: @Appleton: The answer to your question is that the functions are right but the algorithms are wrong. You must not convert to lowercase before converting to titlecase, because if you do you can get wrong answers for certain code points.  Never write `s/(\w+)/\u\L$1/g` because that only works on ASCII.  To be guaranteed to work right on Unicode you must write `s/(\w)(\w*)/\u$1\L$2/g`.  See the difference? There are no roundtrip guarantees on casemapping, **nor are there any guarantees of transitive equality in casemapping.**  In fact, I can find code points where such do *not* hold.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that \u\L$1 converted the whole word to lower case and then converted the first character back to upper case (which I think is what you mean). I guess for the perl version 5.8 which is what I have to use, then your suggestion becomes s/(\p{Word})(\p{Word}*)/\u$1\L$2/g